# Port Number in Wordpress images URL

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Wordpress on my local machine, but I am stuck due to a strange problem. The URL for each of my images is showing a port number:

```
http://localhost:81/sitename/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/logo_dbl1.png
```

Because of this, Wordpress is showing a broken link rather than the image. When I try to upload them, it shows a fake URL in the upload text box.

Comment: What are your WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) configured as? This in in wp-admin, click on settings then general.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because your General Blog Address in the wordpress setup is set to use port 81. Try going to

```
Dashboard > Settings > General blog address
```

And making sure that it has the correct URL (or correct port if you're staying with `localhost`